# Custom order by in sql query

Tags: c#, sql

I am working a report which require custom order by statement.
I have 5 categories which I am using for the `order by` clause. These are my column names 
student expenses, petty cash expenses, home expenses, daily expenses, Fair expenses.
I want to order them in report in this manner:

```
Pettycash
DailyExpense
Home Expense
Fair Expense
Cash Expense
```

Also if new categories are added that wont effect this order and added in the last. I have tried order by asc and desc also searched some forums but it didnt cleared my concept. Thank you.

Comment: plz add some sample output result you need, it would give us better understanding of requirement

Comment: I have provided my code in first answer.. Is there any other method through crystal report i mean through crystal custom functions it will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
ORDER BY
CASE Category
   WHEN 'Pettycash' THEN '1'
   WHEN 'DailyExpense' THEN '2'
   WHEN 'Home Expense' THEN '3'
   WHEN 'Fair Expense' THEN '4'
   WHEN 'Cash Expense' THEN '5'
   ELSE '6' 
END
```

Documentation found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#2).

Comment: I tried to implement the above and got the following error in c#       IERRORINFO.GETDESCRIPTIONFAILED WITH E_FAIL(0X80004005)

Comment: return "select e_date , c_name,description , payment from entry_child where e_date = '" + edate + "' order by case c_name when 'Office Entertainment Expenses' then '0' else '1' end";

Comment: Wooohooo... I did it , all i worked on group expert of report and it worked like a charm... Thank you all for helping and grasping the idea.